# Implementarr Asp.net core identity 2.1 em um projeto criado com databasefirst com dois contextos

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou me deparando com um problema. Abaixo eu executei os seguintes passos:

1) Eu criei um projeto asp.net core web aplication MVC, sem autenticação (Asp.net core 2.2).

2) Por já possuir um banco de dados, usei o esquema DataBaseFirst, então, um contexto foi criado automaticamente.

3) Decidi então adicionar o Asp.Net Core Identity no meu projeto.

O problema é que agora eu tenho dois Contextos, um para o Identity e o outro para o meu banco de dados. Só que o banco de dados é único, portanto, entendo que não deveria haver dois contextos.

Como que eu faço para configurar os dois contextos no Statup.cs com a mesma string de conexão?

Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Você pode herdar o IdentityDbContext do context principal da aplicação, exemplo:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
     : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MessageUser> Message { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityTypeConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MessageUserEntityTypeConfiguration());
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

No caso eu customizei o IdentityUser utilizando a classe ApplicationUser, mas isso é opcional.

```
  public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string CPF { get; set; }

}
```

Referência: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Olá, Rafael! Muito obrigado pelo seu feedback.  Se não for incomodo, teria como você me dar uma dica de como e onde criar essa classe ApplicationUser?

Comment: Olá Hugo, a classe ApplicationUser é só um exemplo, você pode criar a classe com o nome que quiser, o importante aqui é herdar o IdentityUser e no Startup referência-la para que o EF Core possa mapeá-la. Isso você faz no services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>() e também no IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> conforme minha resposta. Adicionei um link de exemplo.

Comment: Boa noite, Rafael!   Vou estudar com carinho essas dicas que voce me passou e ver se consigo avançar no projeto. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.